# Volume Contraction

Tags: dynamical-systems, volume, nonlinear-system, nonlinear-analysis

I need to determine if this system exhibits volume contraction:

$\dot x =yz-x-x^3$

$\dot y =xz-y-y^3$

$\dot z =xy-z-z^3$

My approach is to just calculate the divergence of the vector field F:

$\nabla * F$ = $\partial f_1 \over \partial x$ + $\partial f_2 \over \partial y$ + $\partial f_3 \over \partial z $

This gives $(-3x^2-1)+(-3y^2-1)+(-3z^2-1)$ which is negative for all x,y,z so system exhibits volume contraction.  Is this enough to show that volume contraction is occurring or can I do more?

Comment: Consider the linear system $\dot{x}=\left[\matrix{-1 & 2\\2 & -1}\right]x$. Obviously the divergence of the vector field is negative but trajectories blowup.

Comment: @CTNT: Your example is equivalent to $\dot u_1=-3u_1$, $\dot u_2=u_2$ which is volume contracting.

Comment: @Jay:  Apart from the missing $+$-signs between the three terms your argument is correct.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Maybe we are referring to different definitions of "contraction". According to http://web.mit.edu/nsl/www/preprints/contraction.pdf a region is a contraction region if the Jacobian $\frac{\partial f}{\partial x}$ is negative definite in that region. Using this definition my example system is nowhere contracting.

Comment: Using the above definition, i.e. that the Jacobian must be negative definite in a contracting region you can prove that the above third order system is indeed everywhere contracting.

Comment: @CTNT To support Christian's answer: the OP is asking about _volume_ contraction, i.e. how a flow changes volumes of different domains. Volume contraction means that volume becomes smaller and smaller, but that of course doesn't prevent trajectories from diverging: dissipative saddles were already mentioned in comments above.

Comment: @Evgeny Thanks, for the clarification. Are there any special properties for volume contracting dynamical systems? For example, if we know that a flow is volume contracting and trajectories can be proved to be globally bounded does this mean that they converge to either some equilibrium point or towards a limit cycle?

Comment: @CTNC: you can still get chaos with volume contraction (e.g. with a chaotic attractor, as for Lorenz' map). What you can't get is an absolutely continuous invariant probability measure.

Comment: @D.Thomine Thank you, indeed the Lorentz map is a good example!

Answer (score 4):

We are talking here about a flow $\Phi$ in ${\mathbb R}^3$, defined by an autonomous system of differential equations, i.e., by a vector field ${\bf F}$, and not about a single map $f:\>{\mathbb R}^3\to{\mathbb R}^3$.

If $B_0$ is a tiny "test body" at time $t=0$ then the flow transports and deforms $B_0$ in the time interval $[0,t]$ to a body $B_t$. The question is about the limit
$$\lim_{t\to0+}{{\rm vol}(B_t)-{\rm vol}(B_0)\over t}\ .$$
Doing the computation one finds out that this limit is actually the trace of the Jacobian of the defining vector field ${\bf F}$, times ${\rm vol}(B)$. The OP has found out that this trace is $<0$ everywhere.

Comment: Thank you, I had not encountered that definition before. After my reply I searched a bit and found the relative development in the section 5.1 of "An exploration of dynamical systems and chaos" by Argyris et al.